# How to add a calculated column in a pivot table in excel that takes the values of two pivot table count columns?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot-table, spreadsheet, calculated-columns

So here is the pivot table, and I want to add a calculated column that gives me a win% based off of the L (Loss), T (Tie), and W (Win) COUNT values in the pivot table.

[image: Pivot table]

I tried to add a calculated field but it doesn't let me do that. [image: Inserting Calculated field]

This is how the Win/Loss/Tie raw data looks like.

[image: Win/Loss]